# JavaFX 8: ComboBox button cell update behavior

Tags: combobox, javafx-8

I have a combo box which contains items of type `Dog`. If all items are replaced with new ones (via `setAll` on the `ObservableList` model) , the item renderer can cope with this update, while the button cell renderer cannot:

[image: Button cell renderer does not update correctly]

Here's a minimal example to reproduce the problem ([full source incl. imports on GitHub](https://github.com/netzwerg/java8-playground/blob/b530fcddbb66dc09f7083ee259684d061c6f22dc/src/main/java/ch/netzwerg/fx/ComboBoxRefresh.java)):

```
public class ComboBoxRefresh extends Application {

    private static final class Dog {

        private final String name;

        public Dog(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    private static final class DogListCell extends ListCell<Dog> {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Dog item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null || empty) {
                setText("");
            } else {
                setText(item.name);
            }
        }
    }

    private static List<Dog> createThreeDogs() {
        return range(0, 3).mapToObj(i -> new Dog("Buddy " + i)).collect(toList());
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        ObservableList<Dog> items = observableArrayList(createThreeDogs());
        ComboBox<Dog> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(items);
        comboBox.setPrefWidth(400);
        comboBox.setCellFactory(listView -> new DogListCell());
        comboBox.setButtonCell(new DogListCell());

        Button button = new Button("Refresh");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            List<Dog> newItems = createThreeDogs();
            items.setAll(newItems);
        });

        VBox box = new VBox(10, comboBox, button);
        box.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(box);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

If I add an `equals` implementation to the `Dog` class, everything works, but this is not an option in my real application.

Are there any work-arounds to enforce a proper refresh of the button cell?

Comment: I'm seeing something similar to this. It seems that when the selected value does not exist in the items list, the selected value is rendered with .toString instead of with the button cell. Did you file a bug report?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug. Workaround could be

```
button.setOnAction( event -> {
    List<Dog> newItems = createThreeDogs();
    items.clear();
    items.addAll(newItems);
} );
```

Comment: Tx for your answer. Your workaround loses the selection, thus the button cell renderer cannot misbehave because it no longer has anything to render :) However, your answer inspired me to pragmatically re-apply an index-based selection, which also works in combination with `setAll`...

Comment: @netzwerg glad to hear that. You may post an answer.

Comment: @netzwerg What would you want the selection to be though? If you are replacing all the elements in the combobox, and you don't override equals, then isn't the selected element no longer in the combobox's list? In this case wouldn't it make sense for the selection to be empty?

Comment: @James_D You are totally right, there's no proper way around overriding `equals`. IMHO, the true bug behind my original example is the fact that the selection is *not* lost. The selection model (and thus the button cell) points to an old Dog instance which is no longer part of the model (similar to manually calling `comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(new Dog("Not In Model"))`)